# Bulk delete documents or all documents in a collection in Google Docs

Tags: google-drive

I have a large number (5,000+) of documents in Google Docs and I'd like to delete all of them and/or would like to delete all documents within a collection.

The only native way I see to delete documents is to Ctrl+click highlight them and then delete.  This is impractical for large numbers of docs since you'd have to select docs, delete, go to next page, repeat.

This feature seems obvious (to me) and oddly missing, although I also thought the lack of iPhone copy and paste and the inability to search Gmail attachments were obvious features as well.

How do mass delete documents from Google Docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move a collection to the bin which also moves all documents within said collection.

On the right side menu, go to the collection you want to delete. Click the arrow that appears and click *Move to bin*

Comment: Excellent!  I see why I didn't see this option before.  It's b/c I didn't have my docs in any collection.

Answer (score -1):

Or just go to the right hand side "folder" icon and choose *Open File Picker*.

Comment: How does this delete the documents?