# How I delete all my Google Docs (with no collections)?

Tags: google-workspace, google-drive, delete

A similar question to mine has been [asked before](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14443/bulk-delete-documents-or-all-documents-in-a-collection-in-google-docs) - I want to be able to delete all my Google Docs at once. I used a synchronization app called Syncplicity which synced all my documents with my Google Docs. Unfortunately, due to a bug, it caused loads of errors and problems which I won't go into.

The answer to the question that was asked previously was to

> move a collection to the bin which also moves all documents within said collection

Unfortunately none of my documents are in a collection. I have literally thousands of documents and either bulk selecting the documents page by page and adding them to a category or to the trash bin will take ages. Is there a way to say I want all my documents deleted? I thought of closing my Google Docs account, but I do want to use Google Docs in the future and apparently Google doesn't properly delete the Docs straight away anyway.

Comment: Does the homepage list of document page? also can you go to documents above the list and show all?

Comment: I can click on "All Items" on the left navigation bar. However when I tick the top checkbox to select all items, it only checks all the items on that page. Google Docs only loads the first lot of docs to the page. I can't see how it is possible to select all documents using this method. Even if it were possible, it would probably crash my browser as Google use Javascript for this method.

Comment: Think the only solution I can think of is creating a greasemonkey script to do it all for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to delete all of your Google Docs without using external software:

1. Sign into your Google Docs account
2. On the left hand side, there is a list of different pre-named folders like "Home" and "Starred". There should also be a label called "All Items"--select this.
3. You will see a list of all documents (and collections, if you have any). There will be a check box next to "Title" like this: [image]
4. Select this box, and all of your documents will be selected
5. A new set of options will pop up above the list of documents. Click on the trash icon to delete all of your documents. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [CyberDuck](http://cyberduck.ch/), sign in to your Google Docs account and delete them from there. All at once.

Answer (score -2):

ctrl+A to select all and then press Delete.